# Softether VPN slow throughput

Tags: vpn, softether

I set up a Softether VPN on my Raspberry Pi per [the instructions here](https://gist.github.com/jhenkens/11190151), and I'm getting extremely low throughput when connecting to the VPN. My Internet connection to the Raspberry Pi is about 30 Mbit/s down and 3 Mbit/s up, yet when I connect to the VPN (on another connection that is equally as fast, if not faster), I only get about 1 Mbit/s down & up.
The CPU on the Pi is running at no more than ~5-15% with one connection, so it's not a problem with the hardware as far I as can tell.

How and why am I getting such terrible performance?

Comment: And please, if there's a better way to set this up, feel free to bash my setup. I went with this setup because it was easiest to setup with iOS/OS X devices, and I didn't have to run a VPS. I'm not terribly experienced with VPNs, so any extra information would be welcomed

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue with yours. And I solved it by adding a tab and bridge device between the vhub and eth0. It look like this:

vhub <---> tap0 <---> br0 <---> eth0 (50 to 60 Mbps)

The default set up:
vhub <---> eth0 (1 to 3 Mbps)

It also works for vmware if you use VMXNET3

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This looks like a good answer but you may wish to consider expanding it a bit with some details (e.g. what were the exact steps you took to do this, why you did this/your understanding of what the issue was, etc.) to help others that may not be as familiar with things as you are.

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions:

1. Connect to your VPN server within the same local LAN and test the speed. If you got good throughput with local LAN connection, it would be the networking issue, problem caused by the router, in between your two sites
2. Softether Linux VPN client has built-in throughput testing cmd: TrafficClient and TrafficServer; try to see what speed you can get with these commands
3. You also can try to increase the number of TCP connections with command: AccountDetailSet. That can improve your network throughput, too.

Hope it helps a bit.